# NetLogo error: command expected, i cannot seem to find what is wrong with the code..?

Tags: syntax-error, simulation, netlogo

```
to schooling
  set schoolmates other turtles in-radius 5
  if any? schoolmates 
  [ set nearestNeighbour min-one-of schoolmates [distancemyself]
    ifelse distance nearestNeighbour < 1
    [
      face nearestNeighbour
      right 180
    ]
    [
      rt subtract-headings averageHeading schoolmates heading subtract-headings
    ]
  ]
end
```

Does anybody know why i get this error here? I do not seem to have wrongfully placed brackets..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line.

```
rt subtract-headings averageHeading schoolmates heading subtract-headings
```

The first part

```
rt subtract-headings averageHeading schoolmates
```

is a command in itself so, when Netlogo finishes interpreting it, NetLogo looks for the next command.  But

```
heading subtract-headings
```

is not a command, just some leftover "stuff".  Might it have been mistyped or left over from a previous edit?